# How do I remove recently played with players from my Social menu?

Tags: diablo-iii

I joined a game with a friend the other day and I guess they were in a public game because some random people dropped in and out. Some of these were only in the game for a brief period before leaving, but they all show up in the Recently Played With section of my Social menu.

[Security risk](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149619846) or no, I'm not likely to ever want to interact with these random people. How do I remove listed players from my Social Menu?

Additionally, how do I prevent Diablo 3 from recording and listing recently played with players in the first place so that only friends will be listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't remove them, but you could block those players (right click their name and block communication). Now I'm not entirely sure that also prevents them from joining any of your game. But there is an option under social - friends and chat: `Allow Quick Join`. You could disable this and would have to confirm everytime, someone wants to join your game.

Other than that you are just left with not playing any public games for the moment, until blizzard changes this.